Show $p_t(x)\leq Ct^{-d/2}$ for a random walk in continuous time
Let $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a continuous-time random walk in $\mathbb{Z}^d$ with jump rate $1$ and set $p_t(x)=\mathbb{P}(X_t=x|X_0=0)$ for $x\in\mathbb{Z}^d$. I want to show (for some constant $C>0$):
$$p_t(x)\leq Ct^{-d/2}.$$
For discrete-time random walks $S_n$, this is known and a consequence of the local limit theorem (see e.g. the remark on page 26 here), so
$$p_n(x)\leq C n^{-d/2}\quad (p_n(x)=\mathbb{P}(S_n=x|S_0=0))$$
Question: (How) Can I make use of the discrete case to prove the inequality in continuous time?
My idea: We can view $X_t$ as a composite of a rate-1 Poisson process $N_t$ and a discrete random walk $S_n$, i.e. $X_t=S_{N_t}$ and thus
$$p_t(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{p_n(x)\mathbb{P}(N_t=n)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{p_n(x)\frac{t^n}{n!}e^{-t}}\leq Ce^{-t}\sum_{n=1}^\infty{n^{-d/2}\frac{t^n}{n!}}$$
but I don't know how to proceed.
Any help or comment is greatly appreciated!

Based on your method, we only need to show that for any $k>0$, there exists $C>0$ s.t.
$$f(t):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{n+k}}{\Gamma(n+1+k)}\leq Ce^{t}\quad \forall t>0$$
Note that
$$f'(t)=f(t)+\frac{t^{k-1}}{\Gamma(k)}$$
Hence we have
$$f(t)=e^t\int_0^te^{-x}\frac{t^{k-1}}{\Gamma(k)}dx\leq e^t$$

Thank you for your answer! I understand everything, except the choice of $f(t)$. Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{t^n}{n!n^{d/2}}}\leq f(t)$? For that to be true, $\Gamma(n+1+k)\leq n!n^k$ should hold, but I struggle to see it...

First, you only need to show that $\Gamma(n+1+k)≤C\cdot n!n^k$. Apply Stirling's formula.
